# Creating Animated Image Overlay CSS

Tags: css, overlay, animated

I would like to know how to create this animated, multi-color overlay effect atop an image. This is the example I want to duplicate: http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Bloom/

This is a close as I've gotten using code tested on another site. See code below. It worked with added text but I couldn't successfully integrate the desired image.

```
#colorCycle { background-color: #C30;
padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px; padding-left: 7px;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
animation-name: homeCycle;
animation-duration:6s;
animation-direction:alternate;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;

-webkit-animation-name: homeCycle;
-webkit-animation-duration:6s;
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite; }

@keyframes homeCycle
{
0% {background-color:#006;}
25% {background-color:#060;}
50% {background-color:#CC3200;}
75% {background-color:#603;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes homeCycle
{
0% {background-color:#006;}
25% {background-color:#060;}
50% {background-color:#CC3200;}
75% {background-color:#603;}
}
```